# $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-z_0}=2 \pi i$ -Is this result stay the same if we replace $z_0$ by any point $a \in D(r,z_0)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have shown that if $\gamma=C(r,z_0)$ a circle oriented in the positive direction (direct), then $$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-z_0}=2 \pi i.$$ **Personnal question :** Is this result stay the same if we replace $z_0$ by any point $a \in D(r,z_0)$(a point inside the disk)?

I am not able to response to this question. Any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This answer comes from the definition of [Winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis), which is related to the Residue Theorem and the Cauchy Integral formula.

You can see this even looking at the [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) of the function $f(z)=z-z_0$.

Comment: From the Cauchy Integral formula, how is it possible to do that? with f(z)=1?

Comment: @george: yes, $f\equiv1$ is the choice.